# How to extract data from a facebook permalink?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am part of some secret groups on facebook. Me and my friends want to extract data from some permalinks. i.e. we want extract all the conversation happening on a particular post. Is it possible to do this ?

For e.g. https://www.facebook.com/groups/740390916003559/permalink/740391102670207/

This above link is just an example. It is from a open group hence can be accessed. If the group is not open, it gives and an  error in the graph api.

Comment: What is the purpose of this link when you can not access?

Comment: @KenanZahirovic sorry will change it or add a new link

Comment: @KenanZahirovic please check, I have added a new link

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with "Power Query" for Excel 2010 or Excel 2013.

Go to: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379 and download "Power Query for Excel"

Start "Excel", go to "Power Query" - "From Other sources" - "Facebook".

Set connection like this: [image]

Under "connection" title cllick on record link. Under "comment" click on table link.

Now you should get the result:

[image]

You can now query further, it's up to you. Good luck!

Comment: can you please try to extract data now ? Cause as I have said in the question, it is a secret group.

Comment: I can't access the group via Facebook.com, but I can query it with Power Query. i guess that's your intention, right?

Comment: Yes yes... Let me try it immediately.